# How to delay asking for Facebook timeline post permission until it's needed, with Omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth, koala

For my site, I'm using Omniauth for Facebook authentication, and use Koala to access some misc. data about users.

The site hosts user generated content that's pretty visual, and I used to just use Facebook like button to let people share their content preview to Facebook. However I realized that, due to the nature of the type of content, it's better to post the preview as a photo on their albums (and this is what users want).

However, I don't want to scare away people who just want to try out the service by suggesting them with the permission request to post photos to their timeline when they sign up. Ideally I would want to start out with a default permission with no extended permissions, but let users opt in when they want to share for the first time.

How can I do this? I have read both Omniauth's and Koala's documentations but couldn't find one that describes this particular situation.

Comment: you'll need to have a second login button with a different `scope`